# Confusion with snmp trap

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp

I am new to snmp and after some readings I have 2 questions:-

1) Does net-snmp AUTOMATICALLY sends trap when we configure agent's snmpd.conf file with directives like trapsink, monitor, etc. for inbuilt OIDs like cpu and disk??

I am asking because I am trying to send a trap when cpu goes beyond 90%.
My agent and master are on the same linux box.

My snmptrad.conf file:-

`authCommunity log aaa

 authCommunity log public`

My snmpd.conf file (removing extra comment lines):-

> master agentx   com2sec notConfigUser  default       public
>
> group   notConfigGroup v1           notConfigUser   group
>   notConfigGroup v2c           notConfigUser
>
> view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1   view    systemview
>   included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1   view all    included  .1   view mib2 
>   included  .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2 fc
>
> access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  systemview
>   none none
>
> createUser    internalMonitoringName SHA mysecretpassword AES   rouser
>   internalMonitoringName   iquerySecName internalMonitoringName
>
> com2sec local     localhost       aaa
>     com2sec net-27    10.0.0.0/8      aaa
>     com2sec net-46    10.9.46.0/24    aaa
>     com2sec net-60    10.9.60.0/24    aaa
>     com2sec net-10    10.20.0.0/16    aaa
>
> group MyRWGroup  any        local
>     group MyROGroup  any        net-27
>   group MyROGroup  any        net-46
>     group MyROGroup  any        net-60
>     group MyROGroup  any        net-10
>
> access MyROGroup ""      any       noauth    0      all   none   none
>   access MyRWGroup ""      any       noauth    0      all   mib2   mib2
>
> syslocation "Somewhere in testlab"
>     syscontact Root root@localhost
>
> dontLogTCPWrappersConnects yes
>
> trap2sink localhost aaa
>
> monitor -r 30 machineTooBusy hrProcessorLoad > 90

When I run some process to increase cpu load, the cpu load goes beyond 90% (I can see that in top command) but I can't see the trap message in /var/log/messages.

What I am doing wrong here?

2)  Also, my next question is, if I have a custom MIB file for which I have wrtten an agent, Can I add the variable/OID from that custom MIB with "monitor" directive in snmpd.conf file to send trap AUTOMATICALLY? OR I must send trap from within my agent???

Please help on my confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't send anything automatically.  You have two steps to follow:

1) define *where* you want to send traps or informs.  That's what the `trapsink` and similar lines do.

2) then define *what* you want sent.  That's what the `monitor` and similar directives do.  The `monitor` directive can be used to monitor just about anything, including your own custom MIB variables.

When you include both of these, then it'll send out traps automatically (by doing internal monitoring, and then sending a trap to each configured trapsink or other destination).